# Trying to convert a component of wxVector<m_Product*> that is a wxString to wxStringArray but the program doesn't wanna to

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets

The idea is to convert an wxVector to a wxStringArray so i did a simple function to do it for me, this one:

```cpp
wxArrayString m_ProductStruct::m_ArrayConverter(const wxVector<m_Product*>& m_Prod) {
    wxArrayString m_Temp;
    for (size_t m_ProductCounter = 0; m_ProductCounter < m_Prod.size(); m_ProductCounter++) {
        m_Temp.push_back(m_Prod[m_ProductCounter]->m_Name);
    }
    return m_Temp;
}
```

This function was working beautiful before but now, I dont know whats happening because every time I try something with wxStringArray or some vector, it gives this kind of error:

[image: Image of the error]

By the way, I've tried many ways like making this function a void return and two pass parameters and nothing, still the same error.

My current code that needs the change to wxVector to wxStringArray is this:

```cpp
inline int m_MainClientClass::m_AppendProduct(m_Product* m_ProductData) {
    m_GlobalProductsObject.push_back(m_ProductData);
    m_Products = m_ArrayConverter(m_GlobalProductsObject);
    nlohmann::json m_TempJson;
    for (size_t m_ProductsSize = 0; m_ProductsSize < m_Products.size(); m_ProductsSize++){
        m_TempJson.push_back(m_GlobalProductsObject[m_ProductsSize]->m_Serialize());
    }
    m_ProductsBuffer = m_TempJson;
    m_KUtils::m_ListUpdater(m_Products, *m_ProductsList);
    m_KUtils::m_UpdateConsole(*m_LogConsole, "[K] - Product [" + m_ProductData->m_Name + "] Added ", m_LogConsoleLogBuffer, m_ConsoleGreen, true);

    return 1;
}
```

My includes if necessary:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "m_ProductManager.h"
#include "m_KUtils.h"
#include "m_ProductManagerWindow.h"
#include "m_ProductHeader.h"
#include "m_GlobalHeader.h"
```

Comment: Ensure mProd.size() < m_ProductCounter && m_Prod != nullptr before doing m_Prod[m_ProductCounter]?

Comment: @Omid CompSCI  i think i owe you my ass sir, thanks you.

Comment: Sorry mate, small mistake, it won't happen again

Comment: @KAoTI, keep in mind that it is strongly advised to use the STL containers, especially in the newly written code. So unless you are working with the ancient codebase - I suggest to re-write this using std::vector. wx containers exists only for backward compatibility. It even mentioned in the documentation.